# List all homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z_2}$ to $\mathbb{Z_4}$

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory

I have only come up with two. That is $f(1)=1, f(1)=0$.

Are there any more? If so, how should I go about thinking this problem through, to ensure that I have found all of them?

Comment: There is no homomorpism that sends $1$ to $1$: that would require sending $0$ to $2$ which is impossible. The idea of considering possible values of $f(1)$ is fine, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathbb{Z_2}=\{[0], [1]\}$ and $\mathbb{Z_4}=\{[0], [1], [2], [3]\}$.

The homomorphisms will be determined by $f([1])$, as you have seen. We have too that the order of $f([a])$ divides the order of $[a]$.

The order of $[1] \in \mathbb{Z_2}$ is $2$, so the order of $f([1])$ is $1$ or $2$.

Note that $\mid \mathbb{Z_4}\!\!\mid=4$, so the order of the elements can be $1$, $2$ or $4$ (by Lagrange's Theorem). We list all the elements and see what order they have, and the only elements of $\mathbb{Z_4}$ of order $1$ or $2$ are $[0]$ and $[2]$.

So, from here it follows that the only possible homomorphisms are $f([1])=[0]$ and $f([1])=[2]$.